# ElasticSearch: I want to get count with group by

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following type on ElasticSearch:

```
{
  bundle_id:   11141
  bundle_name: bla_bla
  country:     India
}
```

I want to perform the following query (I'll describe it in SQL):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bundle_id)
FROM my_type
WHERE county IN ('india', 'usa')
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have a look at [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). This is what you are looking for.